# How to create a swipe megamenu for mobile view?

Tags: magento2.3, javascript, menu, mobile-menu

I have created a custom module for Megamenu. In desktop view it looks good and working fine. In mobile view, I want to implement a functionality but I'm not sure how to do that.

The functionality which I want to implement is that when a user clicks on mobile menu icon, the menus will be displayed without any issues. In order to close the menus, user needs to click the body of the web page. We want it to make as a swipe one.

When a user swipe the menu, it should be closed.

Could anyone please help me with this?